# Detect or capture hashbang/querystring change into same href target

Tags: javascript, html, hashbang

I've noticed a couple sites that if I create multiple links that share the same target, the site doesn't actually reload the request, rather it captures the link and handles it, either by loading it into a tab within its application, or changing elements within the page, again... all without reloading the URL request completely.

How do I detect this within my page?

For example, I want to to handle multiple links coming in from external links like this

```
<a href="http://192.168.1.10/index.php?p=1#/tag/ABC-0021" target="myapp">0021</a>           
<a href="http://192.168.1.10/index.php?p=1#/tag/ABC-0031" target="myapp">0031</a>
<a href="http://192.168.1.10/index.php?p=1#/tag/ABC-0012" target="myapp">0012</a>
```

Right now, everytime I click one of those links, my entire app/page just refreshes in the browser tab for that target. Anyone know of a way to prevent this from happening so I can handle it appropriately?

Edit: Google Music does this - try clicking on the links, once you open a tab, move that tab to another monitor/area of your screen. Select another link, notice the content of the Google music changes, but doesn't completely refresh the entire app.
https://jsfiddle.net/jonemzke/

Edit2: I imagine it has something to do with window.onbeforeunload or popstate changes, however I cannot find a specific example of code for this scenario.

Comment: Changing only the hashtag doesn't reload the page, the hashtag work as an in-page anchor generally. You have to add another url query parameter (effectively changes the url) to make a complete site refresh.

Comment: @BrainFooLong that's what i'm trying to prevent - the complete refresh. I want to prevent the refresh, and capture if someone already has an established session within my app to just change certain div tag content.

Comment: Than you are fine with this solution. Checking if the hash has changed only works when you check window.location.hash with an interval if it has changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks guys - in my case here it was because I was actually linking to a local unsecured HTTPS server where I had no valid SSL. I was just using it for testing (and bypassing the security warning), however the browser considers this something that it needs to reload everytime. If you pass to a non HTTPS or a real HTTPS site with the hashes, it doesn't refresh like I wanted!

Answer (score 1):

There's `window.onhashchange` for that

```js
    window.onhashchange = function() {
        document.getElementById("hash").innerText =  window.location.hash;
    };
```

```html
<a href = "#no_refresh">No Refresh</a>
<a href = "#still_no_refresh">Still no Refresh</a>
<br />
Current hash<div id = "hash"></div>
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onhashchange